# Exception while parsing String to Double (NumberFormateException)

Tags: java, android

I have tried other solution ideas from stack overflow but didn't worked.

I am trying to get text from EditText and parsing it to double, but this is giving error of java.lang.NumberFormatException. Please help

here is my code:

```
public double func(double x) {
    String equation = equ.getText().toString();
    Double equ = Double.parseDouble(equation);
    return equ;
}
```

and the exception I got is:

```
11-07 00:32:40.959 25643-25643/com.example.anum.numarics E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "x*x-2.0"
    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
    at com.example.anum.numarics.MainActivity$1.func(MainActivity.java:77)
    at com.example.anum.numarics.MainActivity.bisection(MainActivity.java:41)
    at com.example.anum.numarics.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what don't you understand in `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "x*x-2.0"` ?

Comment: Maybe you shoud re-read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-

Comment: "x*x-2.0" is input which I am entering in textfieled wit id "equ"

Comment: @noor We know that but we're wondering why you think this to be a number.

Comment: @Lothar, now I have got it and found the other way to do so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble` doesn't actually do any sort of math for you.  You're passing `x*x-2.0` in as your string, which is clearly not a number and causes this exception.